# Fetching Multiple Rows from Table and Adding Them into Another Table and then Remove from Previous Table, Using Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

In my administrator page, a list of people that wanted to register to the website will be shown.

Requests are inserted to my `membersneedreg` table. When a user has been accepted, user's row will then be move to the `members` table.

While fetching data from `membersneedreg`, I've added a *checkbox* on each row and decided to have `$num` variable as its value, which increments on every loop.

My problem is how will the system confirm that my checkbox is selected, wherein when submitted, the selected data row will then be move from `membersneedreg` table into `members` table?

Help will gladly be appreciated. If you have any questions or alterations needed on my post, don't hesitate to comment.

```
<?php


$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membersneedreg");   
$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($result_set);    
// Create connection

echo "<table border=1 align='center'>";
echo "<tr><th>MemberID</th><td>FirstName</td><td>LastName</td><td>Date of birth</td><td>Email</td><td>Address</td><td>PostCode</td><td>UserName</td><td>Password</td><td>Annadale Relationship</td></tr> ";       


// Loop over all the posts and print them out
$num=0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_set ) ) {          
  $memberid1 = $row['MemberID']; 
  $fname1 = $row['FirstName'];                              
  $lastn1 = $row['LastName'];   
  $DOB1 = $row['Date_of_Birth']; 
  $Email1 = $row['Email'];
  $Address1 = $row['Address'];                              
  $Postcode1 = $row['PostCode'];   
  $UserName1 = $row['UserName']; 
  $Password1 = $row['Password'];
  $relationship1 = $row['Annadale_Relationship'];
  $num++;  //allows me to give each checkbox a different value.

  echo "<form action='confirm_mem.php'>";
  echo "<tr align='center'><th>$memberid1</th>";                   
  echo "<td>$fname1</td>";                    
  echo "<td>$lastn1</td>";
  echo "<td>$DOB1</td>";   
  echo "<td>$Email1</td>";    
  echo "<td>$Address1</td>";                    
  echo "<td>$Postcode1</td>";
  echo "<td>$UserName1</td>";
  echo "<td>$Password1</td>";   
  echo "<td>$relationship1</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='member' value='$num'></td></tr>";                                     
 }
 echo "</table>";
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Member'>";
 echo "</form>";

 ?>
```

Comment: Dont use **mysql_*** - Its **deprecated**, use `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first convert your ***MySQL*** to ***MySQLi***. I'll put some explanations inside the comments **/* */** as I move forward to the code. 
**IF** you want to hear my advice, you should have just created **2 tables** instead of **2 database**. (Based on your explanation, you call `membersneedreg` and `members` as database).

Assume your `membersneedreg` and `members` are table, AND they both have the same columns.

You can save this, for example, as **form.php**:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH THE CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM membersneedreg");   
$num_messages = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);    

echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";
echo "<tr><th>MemberID</th><td>FirstName</td><td>LastName</td><td>Date of birth</td><td>Email</td><td>Address</td><td>PostCode</td><td>UserName</td><td>Password</td><td>Annadale Relationship</td></tr>";       

/* FETCH THE DATA BASED ON THE QUERY RESULT_GET */

$num=0; /* THIS WILL BE SET AS YOUR COUNTER */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){       

  $memberid1 = $row['MemberID']; 
  $fname1 = $row['FirstName'];                              
  $lastn1 = $row['LastName'];   
  $DOB1 = $row['Date_of_Birth']; 
  $Email1 = $row['Email'];
  $Address1 = $row['Address'];                              
  $Postcode1 = $row['PostCode'];   
  $UserName1 = $row['UserName']; 
  $Password1 = $row['Password'];
  $relationship1 = $row['Annadale_Relationship'];

  $num++;  /* INCREMENT NUM */

  echo "<form action='confirm_mem.php' method='POST'>";
  echo "<tr align='center'><th>$memberid1</th>";                   
  echo "<td>$fname1</td>";                    
  echo "<td>$lastn1</td>";
  echo "<td>$DOB1</td>";   
  echo "<td>$Email1</td>";    
  echo "<td>$Address1</td>";                    
  echo "<td>$Postcode1</td>";
  echo "<td>$UserName1</td>";
  echo "<td>$Password1</td>";   
  echo "<td>$relationship1</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='member[$num]' value='$memberid1'></td></tr>"; 

/* THIS IS IMPORTANT, YOU SHOULD PUT TO AN ARRAY THE VALUE OF THIS CHECKBOX, AND THE VALUE WILL BE BASED ON THE FETCH ARRAY. IN MY EXAMPLE, THE $memberid1 VARIABLE */
  }

  echo "</table>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddencounter' value='$num'>"; /* THIS IS FOR THE COUNTING PURPOSES */
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Member'>";
  echo "</form>";

?>
```

**confirm_mem.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

/* ESTABLISH THE CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$counter=$_POST['hiddencounter'];
$member=$_POST['member'];
echo $counter." submitted checkboxes"; /* TO CHECK HOW MANY CHECKBOX HAS BEEN GENERATED */

for($x=0;$x<=$counter;$x++){

if(empty($member[$x])){ /* IF MEMBER IS EMPTY, DO NOTHING */

}

else {

/* GET THE DATA FROM MEMBERSNEEDREG TABLE */
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM membersneedreg WHERE MemberID='$member[$x]'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$memberid1 = $row['MemberID']; 
$fname1 = $row['FirstName'];                              
$lastn1 = $row['LastName'];   
$DOB1 = $row['Date_of_Birth']; 
$Email1 = $row['Email'];
$Address1 = $row['Address'];                              
$Postcode1 = $row['PostCode'];   
$UserName1 = $row['UserName']; 
$Password1 = $row['Password'];
$relationship1 = $row['Annadale_Relationship'];
}

/* THEN INSERT THE FETCHED DATA TO MEMBERS TABLE */
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, PostCode, UserName, Password, Annadale_Relationship)
VALUES ('$memberid1','$fname1','$lastn1','DOB1','Email1','$address1','$Postcode1','$UserName1','$Password1','$relationship1')");

/* THEN DELETE FROM membersneedreg THE INSERTED DATA */
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM membersneedreg WHERE MemberID='$member[$x]'"); 

} /* END OF ELSE */

} /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

else {
header("LOCATION:form.php"); /* REDIRECT TO form.php IF DIRECTED TO THIS PAGE */
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added and altered this according to my connection, but unfortunately I am still recovering 4-6 undefined index and variable errors on the confirm_mem page.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: hiddencounter in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 14
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0106 258352 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: member in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 15
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0106 258352 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 17
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0106 258352 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0


( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 19
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0106 258352 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0




( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 17
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0106 258352 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0

Comment: @akirk541 replace the for loop with this for($x=0;$x<=$counter;$x++){ AND then run the first code I've provided. I think, you directed your page to confirm_mem.php that is why you had so many errors.

Comment: @akirk541 you can try my updated answer. It's a two file, you can save the first to form.php and the second one is confirm_mem.php

Comment: Its not doing anything to the page or the database now, I have all the connections correct as, I have other php code connect on another page. 
Umm is it possible to have a variable that has a counter and the information from the database into it. Then have that as the checkbox name, so that when the submit button is clicked it submits that to be processes, and work from there?

Comment: Would it be because the check box is not checked as being set?

Comment: @akirk541 already had the counter set on your checkbox. Did you update your code with my updated answer? What is the error now?

Comment: Yes I updated it but now there are no errors but its not removing them from the database.

Comment: But it's inserting in your members table?

Comment: No sorry its not doing that either

Comment: That is weird. Because the code I gave you is working. But the first code is working? Fetching correctly the data from your database table?

Comment: Yea, its displaying it on the form.php fine along with the checkbox.

Comment: And what are the columns in your member's table? Is it exactly the same with the first membersneedreg table?

Comment: They are the exact same so that it would avoid any confusion for myself.

Comment: And what's the structure of your MemberID in your member's table? Is it unique? Auto increment?

Comment: Its a Primary key and Auto increment in both tables

Comment: @akirk541 let's troubleshoot the problem you are getting. Try my updated answer again. I removed the MemberID in insertion, and echo the $counter variable to determine that the count is running.

Comment: When I hit the add member button it just refreshes the page, and the check in the checked box vanishes

Comment: @akirk541 it's because the if condition in your confirm_mem.php didn't met the requirement. Check your submit button. It should be like this : echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Member'>";

Comment: I copyed the code you have put up there and only altered the connections

Comment: I know now the problem. Replace your <form> with this echo "<form action='confirm_mem.php' method='POST'>"; I forgot the method.

Comment: @akirk541 I updated the answer. Put the method tag on the form action, and did put back the memberID in insertion.

Comment: Well it successfully removed it from membersneedreg but didnt submit to the members.  Notice: Undefined variable: address1 in C:\wamp\www\FinalProject\Webpages\confirm_mem.php on line 45
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0009 259448 {main}( ) ..\confirm_mem.php:0

Comment: $Address1 instead of $address1. It's in the insert query. Should be like this:
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Address, PostCode, UserName, Password, Annadale_Relationship)
VALUES ('$memberid1','$fname1','$lastn1','DOB1','Email1','$Address1','$Postcode1','$UserName1','$Password1','$relationship1')");

Comment: @akirk541 how was it?

Comment: mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (FirstName, LastName, Date_of_Birth, Email, Address, PostCode, UserName, Password, Annadale_Relationship)
VALUES ('$fname1','$lastn1','$DOB1','$Email1','$Address1','$Postcode1','$UserName1','$Password1','$relationship1')");
I found the problem. not all the fields were in the insert area. got it working now. thank you so much

Comment: @akirk541 No problem. If my answer helped you solve your problem, don't forget to mark my answer accepted. :)